# How to use react-navigation in react-native native-component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Now I am implementing one React-Native Native-Component by using [create react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob).
It is a very special Component that includes a similar independent app workflow. So I gonna integrate and use the react-navigation engine in this Native-Component engine. I, E Native-Component root is same as below code block.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <NativeStack.Navigator
     initialRouteName="Main"
     screenOptions={{ headerShown: false, screenOrientation: 'portrait' }}
   >
  <NativeStack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStack} />
</NativeStack.Navigator>
```

But I got an empty screen.

When I try normal component rendering, I got the expected effect as below.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Text>{"This is Test"}</Text>
</NavigationContainer>
```

So, finally, What I want to confirm is that my idea(to use the react-native engine in react-native native-component engine scope) is an impossible thing.

Comment: I completely confused. do you want to add react-navigation and you dont know how to do it or you want to add native component(java and swift) to your project?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing description. I gonna use react-navigation in the Native Component. In other words, the Native Component engine includes an independent app workflow which is working with react-navigation.